# subprocess return None what does that mean for my fuzzer

Tags: python, subprocess, output, fuzzer

For school I have to make a fuzzer, I use Charle Miller to fuze pdf files. I want to check to amount of failure of an app. When I do

```py
result = process.communicate()
    print(result)
```

it print (None,None) several times what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

It means that when you created the `subprocess.Popen` object, you did not specify `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE`.

> ### Popen.`communicate`(*input=None, timeout=None*)
>
> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr [...]
>
> `communicate()` returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data). [...]
>
> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) object with `stdin=PIPE`. Similarly, **to get anything other than `None` in the result tuple, you need to give `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE`** [emph. added] too.
>
> — [subprocess - Subprocess Management - Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

For example:

```
import subprocess
apples_only = subprocess.Popen(
    ["grep", "apple"], 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
out, err = apples_only.communicate(b"pear\napple\nbanana\n")

print((out, err))
# (b'apple\n', None)  # did not say stderr=PIPE so it's None.
```

Comment: euh okay I think i get it but by using that how can I know if my fuzzer worked well?

Comment: No idea, I don't know who/what "Charlie Miller" is, or "fuze"ing PDFs, you didn't mention if you're using a separate program as a fuzzer or just controlling one via Python, etc. etc.

Comment: yeah just ahaha i'll read more about the subprocess to try to figure it out